# What do cannabinioids have in common structurally?

Tags: organic-chemistry, biochemistry, structural-biology

I'm looking at the wikipedia page for [cannabinioids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cannabinoid), and trying to find structural similarities between them. For plant based ones it's hard enough, the only similarity I could find seemed to be 6 member rings and medium sized hydrocarbon chains. When you include endocannabinoids, it seems to get more complicated. What structural similarities do cannabinioids share?

Comment: The 1,3 oxygens off the phenyl ring and the hydrophobic alkyl chain in the 5 position, and a further hydrophobic region away from the phenyl ring attached by one or more oxygen

Comment: @Waylander Ok, thanks now that I see it I'm embarresed I didn't see it earlier, but clearly this doesn't extend to endocanabinoids like anandamide or NADA.